# NSTextField's autocompletion method

Tags: objective-c, macos, autocomplete, delegates, nstextfield

I'm having problem triggering `complete:` method for NSTextfield.

for now I can make an distinct array of names from a textfield using `@distinctUnionOfObjects` ( awesome method to remove duplicates of an array ) and now I can send back autocompletion for this textfield using:
 `- (NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index`

But, this method is not automatic and I have to press **ESC** button to pop the autocompletion suggestion up for the textfield during data entry.

I searched here and found some examples that make no sense for me.

**Short Question:**
Is there any method using **NSTexfields delegates** like `controlDidChanged` or something like that to do this more easily and clearly ?

I just confuse using `complete:` method for nstextview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your text field delegate gets `controlTextDidChange:`, you can call `complete:` on the [Field Editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001815-CJBJHGAG).  This is the method that gets called when you press ESC or F5.

```
- (void) controlTextDidChange: (NSNotification *)note {
    NSTextView * fieldEditor = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];

    [fieldEditor complete:nil];
}
```

The tricky part is that when the completion menu is being navigated, it will cause `controlTextDidChange:` messages to be sent again, (although without changing the actual string) which will create an infinite loop. You will need some kind of flag to stop `complete:` from being called when you are already in the middle of a completion. For example, you can keep track of the last change the user made to the string and compare it with the current value of the field editor; if there's no user-initiated change, don't cause completion:

```
BOOL textDidNotChange = [lastTypedString isEqualToString:[fieldEditor string]];

if( textDidNotChange ){
    return;
}
else {
    lastTypedString = [[fieldEditor string] copy];
    [fieldEditor complete];
}
```

Comment: @Josh Caswell,  ... and you think this is smart way to do this extremely simple request ?

Comment: @Prooshani: I don't understand your comment. You think the procedure I've described is too complicated?

Comment: @Josh Caswell, No My friend, I just Trying to tell you I read this trick before and I think this a weakness of xcode that make me to do **tricks** for a very simple request that handled in other languages easily !
Also, you can imagine that I have 22 Textfields and have to do this for all of them !
Now, do you think this is smart method from Xcode ?
Note: I read this trick in apple's documents before.

Comment: Anyway, I tried this:  
`if ([aNotification object]== customerNameField) {`  
        `bool customerNameDidChanged=[customerNameTemp isEqualToString:[customerNameField stringValue]];`  
        `if (customerNameDidChanged==false) {`  
            `customerNameTemp=[[customerNameField stringValue ]copy];`  
           `NSTextView * fieldEditor = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];`  
            `[fieldEditor complete:nil];`  
        `}`  
    `}`  

and then autocompletion poping up but it's duplicate my textfield's string after typing first word of name !!!

Comment: Don't forget the `!` operator on the result of `isEqualToString:`. I'll edit my post to make this clearer.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, I knew about the function of `Bool textdidchange` and etc,But this not work very well for me !

Comment: @Proshani This has nothing to do with Xcode.  This is how that library /framework was designed.

Comment: @Josh Caswell,I done what I found in Apple's documents and it's working with some buggy ways.
when I start putting data in `textfields` it's start completion but I can't able to remove worlds that I typed to the last word !
to remove last word I have to cancel `autocompletion` by pushing **ESC** and then I can clear my `textfield`completely.
Do you have any suggestions my friend ?

Comment: @Prooshani: When you're in the middle of completion, and the menu is showing, the menu grabs some of the key events. You can act on some of them in `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:`. Unfortunately this is an area where if you want much customization, you run into the need to subclass the text field really quickly.

Answer (score 7):

I don't recommend copying the whole string.  It would be fine for your case, but if you're using autocompletion for a large text file, then you'll have all kinds of performance and memory issues.  You can just keep track of whether or not you are in the middle of an update. If you have multiple textviews, you could make a dictionary for the isCompleting variables.

```
- (void) controlTextDidChange: (NSNotification *)note {
    NSTextView * fieldEditor = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];

    if (!isCompleting) {
        isCompleting = YES;
        [fieldEditor complete:nil];
        isCompleting = NO;
    }
}
```